# What kind of SSL certificate do I need?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https

I want to install HTTPS on my server and I wonder what kind of certificate I will need and where I can buy it.

The site is a web application that demands high security by it's users since they store sensitive business data.

I am also integrating a third party payment gateway into the register process of the site and need a secure way to send credit card data one way. I do not intend to store this data in our own database.

So, what do I need? And also, how do I install it on Ubuntu Server 9.10 / Apache2 ?

Cheers!
Christoffer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a normal one, and you buy it at a registrar. RapidSSL is pretty decent - I use them. Start.com is free, and most browsers recognize it, too. You need a normal certificate - not wildcard, normal server certificate.

To send the data to the credit card provider you dont need anything - the provider will have a SSL certificate on his end, and you just make sure it is valid-

How to install Ubuntuu Server 9.10 and Apache 2 - seriously, if yo uwant to run a shop better ask someone. This is getting a LOT too low for someone who is going to deal with credit cards, imho.

Comment: +1 for getting professional assistance. There's a lot of rules you're *meant* to follow when dealing with credit cards, like using AES encryption if you're going to store them for future reference, and the rules to make up the cypher key for the encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-certificate-wizard.html to get an idea of the type of certificates out there.